# iOS navigation top bar is black on launch and close of application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

When closing or opening my application, my navigation bar seems to turn black for a moment and then if opening returns to normal. It is normally a white bar, with black text as is default. I don't know if my app background is interfering, but that is blue so it wouldn't make perfect sense. Attached is a photo of the bar while opening the app. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question by reading about some related issues that weren't exactly identical, but they involved the same concept. They proper way to fix this issue is to go in the app delegate and change the window color. Not sure how it got broken, but this will do the trick.

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```